# How to upload multifile with file field 2D array?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, media

I have using Jquery multi box upload with php.

X = loop value

```
<label>Attachment</label><input type="file" name="newfiles[]['+ x +']" accept="ppt|doc|xls|pdf" multiple="" />
```

**Where need to change in this set of code? this one code for one dimension how to apply 2d**

```
foreach ($_FILES['newfiles']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {

            $file_name = $_FILES['newfiles']['name'][$key];
            $file_size = $_FILES['newfiles']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['newfiles']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['newfiles']['type'][$key];

}
```

**print_r($_FILES['newfiles']);**
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is exactly your problem ?

Comment: Well seems like you are on your way. Have you tried writing the data to a more permanent location? It would be almost the exact same if you were working with a single file...

Comment: i have added multi file attachment with multiple boxs.

Comment: Wow, why do you need a 2D array for that?

Comment: i have added screen wait

Answer (score 0):

You are currently retrieving an array. You need to get the first element of this array :

```
foreach ($_FILES['newfiles']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
    $file_name = reset($_FILES['newfiles']['name'][$key]);
    $file_size = reset($_FILES['newfiles']['size'][$key]);
    $file_tmp = reset($_FILES['newfiles']['tmp_name'][$key]);
    $file_type = reset($_FILES['newfiles']['type'][$key]);
}
```

Comment: as you cant get how-many keys are there. so you need to use foreach  loop. as discribe in my answer.

Comment: this is inside your foreach

Comment: Ok, now it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like:

```
foreach($array['name'] as $key => $value){
  $name = $value;
  $size = $_FILES['newfiles']['size'][$key];
  $tmpname = $_FILES['newfiles']['tmp_name'][$key];
  $type = $_FILES['newfiles']['type'][$key];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When uploading multiple files with the same field name, another dimension is added to the array.We will get:

```
 foreach($array['name'] as $key => $value){
     $file_name = $_FILES['newfiles']['name'][$key];
     $file_size = $_FILES['newfiles']['size'][$key];
     $file_tmp = $_FILES['newfiles']['tmp_name'][$key];
     $file_type = $_FILES['newfiles']['type'][$key];
 }
```

You can take a reference from here :
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: i know this one but i have use 2D array.